# Reuse hard-drive from ESXi 4.0 server in ESXi 5.5?

Tags: vmware-esxi, hard-drive

I have a disk, which I would like to use in a new ESXi 5.5 server.

It was used as a data store and contains VMs we would like to use on the new server.

The hard-drive is SATA 3Gb which I believe is compatible with the 5.5 server

Can I just place this in the new server? Do I need to go through any steps to convert the VMs? Is there anything else to consider?

Comment: Why the down-vote? I looked widely on the web for a solution, but nobody addressed it clearly. Maybe the question was too easy - but not everyone knows the answer. That's why these forums exist. So please take away the down-vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I just place this in the new server?

Yes

> Do I need to go through any steps to convert the VMs?

No

> Is there anything else to consider?

You might want to convert the VMFS on the disk to the latest version.

Comment: You'll also want to update the VMware tools and virtual hardware (now referred to as VM Compatibility in the web client) to the versions supported on your new host.